# javascript minus one month return first day of current month when month day is 31

Tags: javascript, date

Usually I minus one month from current date like below:

```
//assuming today is 2018-05-30T09:50:05.345Z

var d = new Date;
console.log(d);
// return : 2018-05-30T09:50:05.345Z

d.setUTCMonth( d.getUTCMonth() -1 );
console.log(d);
//return : 2018-04-30T09:50:05.345Z
```

but suppose, today is the 31 of the month and this doesn't work anymore... ex:

```
//assuming today is 2018-05-31T09:54:23.850Z

var d = new Date;
console.log(d);
// return : 2018-05-31T09:54:23.850Z

d.setUTCMonth( d.getUTCMonth() -1 );
console.log(d);
//return : 2018-05-01TT09:54:23.850Z
```

instead of setting date to previous month, date is set to first day of month (same append with `d.setMonth(d.getMonth - 1)`

what am I missing?

Comment: You're not missing anything, this is just the way it was specified. You might want to look into (the source code of) moment.js which handles [additions/subtractions](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) differently than vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

When you put static value like  `dateObj.setUTCMonth(4);` it is showing the same i.e. `2018-05-01` but if we put `var dateObj = new Date(); dateObj.setUTCMonth(dateObj.getUTCMonth()-1,30); console.log(dateObj);` it works.This is JS issue. If you want to use the same code, you need to check  the number of day in  month & then execute the condition basis code.